# Can't connect to internet after installing dummynet ipfw in Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, ipfw

Recently i just finished installing dummynet ipfw in Windows 8.1. I need to deactivate digital siganture requirements before able to install it. But after install it, desktop shows Test Mode 9600 on corner right down of desktop. After i removed it then i couldn't connect to internet until i uninstall dummynet from my network adapter. I wanted to work in dummynet ipfw but it seems impossible. Is there any solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check default ipfw rule. On FreeBSD initial ipfw ruleset typically defaults to `ipfw add 65536 deny all from any to any` and that's probably what stops your traffic.

You'll need to add a rule that would allow your traffic to get in and out to get your traffic going and, possibly, directed towards dummynet pipes, etc.